# Opening file via hyperlink causes VS to stop debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-office

This is a rather odd problem i am running into

I currently have a web page that i am adding hyperlinks to that when clicked will open a file (usually Word file though there are some Excel files).

Here's the problem. When debugging all of the files do open properly, however, files labeled .doc, .docx, or .xls all end up stopping debug mode when they open. I have .docm files that open properly and do not stop debugging. There isn't an error thrown anywhere just a forced stop of debug mode it seems.

Has anyone ran into a problem similar to this? I have only tested locally but i am unsure if it will cause problems when putting it on the test server. I'm still not quite done with the rest of the page so i was hoping to stop this behavior before completeing the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you open these documents in the same windows that you are debugging, or do you use a target attribute in the anchor to try to open them in a new window?

Also, you probably have your VS debug mode set to automatically attach to IE in order to debug script. When the web page unloads (in favor of loading the Office document), it might signal to VS that the debugging session is ended.

Rather than pressing F5 (Debug) to start your debugging session, I would just use the Debug menu, Attach to Process... command, and find the w3wp.exe that is running your application. That will allow you to debug the server-side part of your app without connecting to IE to do script debugging.

Alternately, you can turn of script debugging using IE's advanced options. You will get a warning from VS when you click Debug, but you can also turn that off using VS Options.

Comment: Thats what it was. IE by default tries to open files that it knows in the same window. What was happening was it didn't recognize .docm so it was prompting to open or save the file. .doc, .docx, .xls however are all filetypes that IE can handle and so it was opening it in the same window and killing the w3wp causing VS to think i was done debugging. The solution i used was to set the target property to _blank to force a new tab to be opened. Thanks for the explanation.